# HBase or Hive for Large number of Variables

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hive, apache-pig

I have a csv file with more than 2500 variables and I wanted to put it in Hadoop cluster with either HBase, Hive Table or Pig. Since number of variables is extremely large hence I am not able to understand which method is going to be time effective.

Any pointer in this direction will be very helpful.

Comment: What do you mean, "more than 2500 variables"?  You have over 2500 columns?  Maps with a variety of fields?  How will you know what all these 2500 variables mean, whatever you use?

Comment: Yes WinnieNicklaus. 2500 Columns is what I meant. All of them are either Character or Numeric (No mapping also). And the Header or first row contians the name of it. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: What do you want to do with this data?  The use case is important to the choice of storage.

Comment: @EricZBeard hits it: the use case is paramount: hbase has near real time query but very simply query semantics. Hive has complex query capabilities but is batch oriented.